# ordered requests parameters python

Tags: python, post, python-3.x, parameters, python-requests

How can I post ordered params in requests?

I have tried the following, but none of them work:

```
payload = dict{('f','1'),('s','2'),('t','3'),('f','4'),('ft','5'),('s','6'),('se','7'),('e':8,'data[1]','9'),('t','10'),('el','1q'),('data[2]','12'),('data[3]','13'),('data[4]','14'),('htmldata[5]','15')}

payload = OrderedDict{('f','1'),('s','2'),('t','3'),('f','4'),('ft','5'),('s','6'),('se','7'),('e':8,'data[1]','9'),('t','10'),('el','1q'),('data[2]','12'),('data[3]','13'),('data[4]','14'),('htmldata[5]','15')}

payload = (('f','1'),('s','2'),('t','3'),('f','4'),('ft','5'),('s','6'),('se','7'),('e':8,'data[1]','9'),('t','10'),('el','1q'),('data[2]','12'),('data[3]','13'),('data[4]','14'),('htmldata[5]','15'))

payload = ([('f','1'),('s','2'),('t','3'),('f','4'),('ft','5'),('s','6'),('se','7'),('e':8,'data[1]','9'),('t','10'),('el','1q'),('data[2]','12'),('data[3]','13'),('data[4]','14'),('htmldata[5]','15')])
```

The error I am getting is:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This one post parameters in random order without an error:

```
payload = {'f':'1','s':'2','t':'3','f':'4','ft':'5','s':'6','se':'7','e':8,'data[1]':'9','t':'10','el':'1q','data[2]':'12','data[3]':'13','data[4]':'14','htmldata[5]':'15'}
```

How can I post ordered params using the following code?

```
c = requests.post(url, params = payload)
```

Comment: The OP's knowledge of python appears limited to me, but the question __How can I post ordered params using `requests`?__ is valid. The `requests` documentation only states that a dictionary should be passed as the `data`/`params` argument, and mentions nothing about how to order the keys. The HTTP specification states that `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` should be passed "in the order they appear in the document" [8.2.1](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_8.html#SEC8.2.1). So if you happen to be automating a form post, you may need this information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `dict{...}` is wrong, it should be `dict(...)`. Same goes for `OrderedDict{...}`
- `dict` and `OrderedDict` take a sequence as argument
- you have `('e':8,'data[1]','9')` within your list of tuples. Should probably be `('e',8),('data[1]','9')`.

This produces a **dict** (it's equivalent to the working dict literal you posted), which will **always be unordered**:

```
payload = dict([('f','1'),('s','2'),('t','3'),('f','4'),('ft','5'),('s','6'),('se','7'),('e', 8),('data[1]','9'),('t','10'),('el','1q'),('data[2]','12'),('data[3]','13'),('data[4]','14'),('htmldata[5]','15')])
```

This produces a **tuple of tuples**, which **requests doesn't take** as argument for `data`:

```
payload = (('f','1'),('s','2'),('t','3'),('f','4'),('ft','5'),('s','6'),('se','7'),('e', 8),('data[1]','9'),('t','10'),('el','1q'),('data[2]','12'),('data[3]','13'),('data[4]','14'),('htmldata[5]','15'))
```

The remaining two (**ordered dictionary** and **list of tuples**) will produce what you want:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
payload = OrderedDict([('f','1'),('s','2'),('t','3'),('f','4'),('ft','5'),('s','6'),('se','7'),('e',8),('data[1]','9'),('t','10'),('el','1q'),('data[2]','12'),('data[3]','13'),('data[4]','14'),('htmldata[5]','15')])
payload = [('f','1'),('s','2'),('t','3'),('f','4'),('ft','5'),('s','6'),('se','7'),('e', 8),('data[1]','9'),('t','10'),('el','1q'),('data[2]','12'),('data[3]','13'),('data[4]','14'),('htmldata[5]','15')]
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarity on this. I was looking for a way to order the POST parameters, and *just* tried `OrderedDict` which worked perfectly. I don't see [any documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/?highlight=post#requests.post) mentioning that the `data` argument for `request` can take a list of tuples as an argument. Where did you gather this information? Thanks!

Comment: Mainly by looking at the source... The relevant pieces are in [`RequestEncodingMixin._encode_params`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/9dc660269f3270cf60ba5e1fd855e853241218d5/requests/models.py#L76) and [`to_key_value_list`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/9dc660269f3270cf60ba5e1fd855e853241218d5/requests/utils.py#L145) (have a look at the comments and examples). Basically this means it can take either a mapping or any iterable that yields two-tuples (most parameters wich can be given as mapping do the same).

Comment: fantastic digging. The docstring on `_encode_params` provides the details I was looking for: `"Will successfully encode parameters when passed as a dict or a list of 2-tuples. Order is retained if data is a list of 2-tuples but arbitrary if parameters are supplied as a dict."` In my case, the server was rejecting the form if the POST form data was out of order. Using a list of tuples `[(a,b), ...]` fixed the problem.